# How to select a set of rows from a table by matching columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

silly question.
I have a table like this

```
CODE        |         ID_C                                                                                                                                                           
--------------------------                                                                                                                                                           
IUS/06      |         0108                                                                                                                                                           
IUS/06      |         0108                                                                                                                                                           
MAT9        |         0124                                                                                                                                                           
MAT9        |         0124                                                                                                                                                           
MAT9        |         0124                                                                                                                                                           
PROGR12     |         0124                                                                                                                                                           
PROGR12     |         0124                                                                                                                                                           
PROGR12     |         0124                                                                                                                                                           
PROGR12     |         0124
TEC12       |         0150
SNT6        |         0150
FPN3        |         0103
BSD9        |         0103
```

and another table like this :

```
ID_C
----
0150
0108
```

and a last one like this :

```
ID_C
----
0124
```

Now. I want to visualize all the rows from the first table that has id_c equal to any of the id_c from the second table AND id_c equal to the one in the third table. now the third table is more like a single datum while the second table is a collection of data. In the example this will produce in output the first table minus the row with ID_C = 0103.

Thank you for your time, this sql novice salutes you.

Comment: You'll want to `INNER JOIN` the two tables together on those columns

Comment: actually the problem is a bit different because the second table are actually 2 tables : in the first we find 0124 and in the other 0108, sorry for the error !

Comment: can you change your sample data to in your question to reflect this requirement?

Comment: here you go, and thank you from your time.

Comment: my first tought was to accorpate the last two datasets with something like a "vertical join" to obtain a table wich contain all the possible values that i need to select in the first table. In this example the result table will be something with 3 rows ( 2 from the 2nd + 1 from the 3rd ).

Comment: Got ahead of myself...  Just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why make it so complex it can be just this:

```
SELECT CODE, ID_C
FROM table1st
WHERE ID_C IN (SELECT ID_C FROM table2nd)
   OR ID_C IN (SELECT ID_C FROM table3rd)
```

Comment: it theorically works. But,  truth to be told, table 2nd and table 3rd are actually two result sets obtained from other queries. i wanted something like that because i've already resolved part of the problem and that solution fit better into mine. your works as well, but i should rearrange the outer query totally. Of course your answer is based on my question, so it's fine. Best regards

Comment: With a little bit of modifications, i actually made your solution work too. Very elegant, thank you

Comment: Just for clarity, since the 2nd and the 3rd table where result-sets, i used a subquery as the IN parameter

Answer (score 1):

You'll still want an `INNER JOIN`, just a bit more complex one:

```
SELECT 
  t1.CODE,
  t1.ID_C
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT ID_C FROM table2 t2
   UNION
   SELECT ID_C FROM table3 t3) un 
ON t1.ID_C = un.ID_C
```

[Here's a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d038/3) of this query in action.

There are duplicate rows in table1, but if you don't want duplicates in this result set, you can change the first `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT`.  Just be aware that this will incur a (sometimes severe) penalty in  performance.

What I did was `UNION` the second and third tables together to get one big set of all the `ID_C` values I was interested in, then used `INNER JOIN` to restrict the rows of `table1` to only those rows that had those values.

[Technet: INNER JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx)

[Technet: UNION](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: brilliant! so you can actually do such a thing. It worked like a charm ! thank you very much!

Comment: @user1888132 As you learn more about SQL and set theory, you will be amazed at what is actually possible...